# Conflict folder move Dropbox API?

Tags: dropbox-api

I am trying to move some files from one folder to another.

This is my curl request:

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/move \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer faketokenjskahdLDAKHDALjdj8287ew98ehsahdkkadjhk' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"from_path":"/folder1","to_path":"/folder2/folder2.1"}'
```

Whenever I call it I get this reponse:

```
{
  "error_summary": "to/conflict/folder/...",
  "error": {
    ".tag": "to",
    "to": {
      ".tag": "conflict",
      "conflict": {
        ".tag": "folder"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The docs say the following about the specific key words in the response:

```
conflict :  Couldn't write to the target path because there was something in the way.

folder:  There's a folder in the way.
```

How can there be a folder in the way? What does this even mean? I'm not sure what to do to solve this issue.

Docs for the `/move` endpoint can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-move)

Comment: My assumption would be that there's already a folder at the path `/folder2/folder2.1`. Is that not true?

Comment: There is only another folder in folder2 - folder2.2. But nothing inside folder 2.1. Would that be interfering?

Comment: I deleted folder 2.2 and retried the call but still getting the same error. The only other folder is folder 3 in the main directory but that shouldn't be causing the problem. Folder 2 has 2 folders, and folder 1 has 20 xml files that I want to move to 2.1 which is empty

Comment: okay - so I deleted folder2 and was able to execute the call successfully but it doesn't really do what I want it do. I want to move/cut the contents of folder1 to folder 2.2 without creating new folders, and without getting rid of folder 1 (but removing the items in folder1). Am I going to need to use /copy and /delete with every file in the folder to do this?

Comment: Urg... trying to use /copy now and still getting the same conflict error! Why can't I copy my files to an existing directory....

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205162963-folder-in-the-way-conflict-error-when-using-move-API-endpoint- ]

Comment: @smarx since you also work at Dropbox it might be worth checking out the discussion in the forum that Greg referenced

Comment: @jgozal I saw it. My original comment seems to be correct.

Comment: @smarx yes but my point in the forum post is that `to_path` is defined as the destination in the docs. The docs don't say anything about having to specify what needs to go inside the destination in `to_path` so in my eyes, moving folder1 to folder2/folder2.1 meant moving the contents of folder1(when it really moves the whole folder with its contents) to folder2.1(when folder2.1 is not really a destination, but the name of the new file/folder that you are creating in the destination).

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the semantics of `mv` and `cp` in the Linux/Mac world (or `move`/`copy` on Windows). There, if the destination already exists and is a folder, the file you're moving keeps its original filename and gets moved *under* that folder. E.g. `mv /foo /bar` might result in the file being at `/bar` or it might result at the file being at `/bar/foo` depending on whether `/bar` already existed as a folder. I know that's a common behavior, but it's actually *very* confusing and hard to deal with in code. Dropbox's behavior is how most programmatic moves work.

Comment: @smarx I use linux to do my work on a daily basis and it never occurred to me that the API would work like mv and cp because I was following the documentation of the API which indicated otherwise (i.e description of move when source path is a folder says "moves folder's contents" and not "moves folder"). In any case, whenever you make an mv in linux and the destination folder exists, it doesn't give you a conflict error - it just moves `foo` inside `bar` as you mentioned. So the API endpoint doesn't really work like `mv`.

Comment: @jgozal Right, I'm pointing out that the way Linux `mv` works is weird, and Dropbox doesn't work that way. BTW, the documentation says "Move a file or folder to a different location in the user's Dropbox. If the source path is a folder all its contents will be moved." I think the first sentence is pretty clear. The second is just to make sure people understand the contents get moved as well.

Comment: @smarx, the second statement is the one that confused me. Quite frankly if the first one says that the endpoint moves a folder, any reasonable person assumes that the contents of the folder will be moved with it as well... Where would the contents go if not? The second statement seems to be trying to clarify exactly the opposite: that if the path provided is just a folder, it will only move its contents. I guess its up to interpretation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this to work by requesting a list of the files in folder1/ then looping through each one of them and moving them `from_path` folder1/filename `to_path` folder2/folder2.1/filename

I needed to put the file name at the end of both paths to avoid any conflicts!

Comment: if you were able to move each file to "/folder2/folder2.1" without explicitly creating "/folder2/folder2.1" that must mean that the folder "folder2.1" in "/folder2" already existed, right?  If "folder2.1" already exists it seems like the error is correct.

Comment: @brbob yup the folder already existed. I was under the impression that the folder needed to exist, as the `to_path` parameter is described in the docs as the path of the destination. Destinations are usually predefined.